# list with checkBox

Tags: android

I have a list adapter and this is my getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView= myInflater.inflate(R.layout.index, null);
        holder= new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        holder.checkBox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Check);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(lista.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

and in my xml file of this activity i have the Checkbox  invisible... because when I press the bottom I want that appears all checkbox in my list, I do this...

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item){
    checkButton= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Check);

        if (item.getItemId()== 2){
            for (int i =0; i< myAdapter.getCount(); i++){
                //myAdapter.getItemId(i);
                checkButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

But with this only appears one checkBox in the top of the list and not in the other elements of the list... How a can fix this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
if(//ur condition)
{
view.findViewById(R.id.Check).setVisibility(CheckBox.VISIBLE);
}
//ur method
}
```